# Why is my usable RAM only half of my Installed RAM?

Tags: windows-10, memory

I recently installed another 8GB of RAM, but my computer isn't able to use it. Apparently, it's all "hardware reserved." I don't think that Windows 10 needs 8GB of RAM to run, and I would like to be able to use the memory I installed. Can anyone help?

My MB is the MS-7693 970 Gaming by MSI, and the memory in question is Corsair Vengeance (CMZ8GX3M1A1600C10)

[image: 16.0 GB (7.95 GB usable)]

Comment: This is most likely a problem with the firmware. Have you checked relevant BIOS settings yet? A driver could theoretically also be to blame. Consider trying with Linux (Live CD/USB) and also check Windows Setup (use Shift-F10 to bring up a console, then start ˋtaskmgrˋ.

Comment: @somebadhat I've added my MB and memory to the question.

Comment: I've got 2x4GB and 1x8GB. the 4GB sticks work fine

Comment: Nope, the 2x4GB are PV38G186C0K

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102865/discussion-between-somebadhat-and-owen).

Answer (score 2):

Read about [mixing](https://www.google.com/search?&q=Windows+10+Won%E2%80%99t+Use+Full+RAM) computer memory.

Identify your motherboard with powershell. See if your choice of motherboard and cpu supports 16GB of the type of memory you have installed by reading your manual.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BaseBoard | Format-Table Manufacturer, Product, SerialNumber, Version
```

Identify your memory with powershell:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory | Format-Table Manufacturer,Banklabel,Configuredclockspeed,Devicelocator,Capacity,Serialnumber -autosize
```

If you have used a supported amount / type of memory read the following.

[Windows 10 Won’t Use Full RAM](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+10+will+not+use+full+amount+of+memory)

- Windows 32-bit can only use up to 4GB of RAM.
- If you have an integrated GPU you cannot use the full memory as an integrated GPU uses memory from your RAM.
- Defective RAM.

Comment: My RAM is supported by my MB (MS-7693) and modifying RAM on Boot didn't do anything for me. I don't really know how to change my BIOS settings, but I do know how to get into my BIOS, just once I'm in there I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 detected a problem with the 8GB RAM that you recently installed, and is reserving it so that it does not get used.

Your computer may have one of these problems.

- The new RAM stick is bad.
- There is a bad memory slot in the motherboard. Try swapping the RAM stick around to another slot.
- The new RAM stick is not compatible with your computer's hardware.

Run the Memory Diagnostic tool in Windows 10 to troubleshoot the problem.

1. Click the lower-left Start button on the desktop to expand the Start menu, and then select *Settings* in it.
2. Type "Diagnose your computer’s memory problem" in the search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Follow the on-screen instructions to run it.

[image: Windows Memory Diagnostic]

If the new RAM is not compatible with the version of Windows 10 that is installed the Memory Diagnostic tool will report it.

If you have a Linux live USB handy, it may show a message about the RAM on the screen when booting the USB to a live session. If you take a photo of this message and search for it online it will help you to troubleshoot the problem. It has been my experience that if a RAM stick is bad the relevant message will appear on an otherwise empty black screen for less than a second right after the manufacturer's splash screen disappears when the computer is booting.

Comment: I used the Memory Diagnostic but Windows didn't detect a problem with the memory.

Comment: You should use something like memtestx86 which is much more extensive then the memory diagnostic built-into Windows

Comment: Memtest[memtest](https://www.memtest86.com/) runs from a USB stick to check your RAM. [Crucial.com](https://www.crucial.com/) has a different free utility for checking/identifying RAM (and they will try to sell you the correct type; albeit at decent prices from what I've seen.)

Answer (score 0):

After going through hell and every possible solution out there I have another one to add to the list:

- Make ABSOLUTELY SURE that your RAM slots are not polluted. I had a tiny amount of dust in one of these slot's which caused this issue.

3 hours of troubleshooting because of this tiny dustcorn -_-
Everything back to normal now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, (4 x 8gb sticks) 16gb worked the other 16gb just reported in task manager as hardware reserved, tried everything initially no joy. I then noticed two of the ram were rated faster, so I removed all the memory and installed only the faster memory, the computer rebooted like 3 times just after bios screen then eventually into windows. I then powered down added slower ram  and rebooted straight into Windows. All memory is now available. Just sharing what worked for me.