# 12gb of ram but windows 10 says 3.48gb is usable

Tags: windows-10, memory, upgrade

I have recently upgraded my windows 10 laptop from 4gb to 12gb of ram. However, windows says that 3.48 gb is usable. This was also the case when I had only 4gb installed.

I just checked the BIOS and ran a memory check that took around 30 minutes. But it said that the memory was fine, and windows boots just fine as well.

SYSTEM INFO:

> Bios Version: F.44
>
> Bios Vendor: Insyde
>
> Bios Setup Utility: InsydeH20 setup Utility
>
> Bios Setup Utility Revision: 3.5
>
> Processor: AMD(r) A6-3420M APU With AMD Radeon(r) HD 6520G Graphics
>
> Graphics: AMD Radeon(r) HD 6520G Graphics
>
> Ram: 12.0GB, 3.48GB Usable by Windows
>
> Operating System: Windows 10
>
> Architecture: ACPI x64

Added Ram: 8GB Green Rasalas Ram from Amazon

Motherboard: Unknown

In conclusion, should I be worried? Is this just a bug with Windows 10 Update 1909? Does it mean that the Rasalas 8GB Ram Stick in my computer is unusable?

EDIT: I was looking around, and I discovered that a whopping 8.5 gb is hardware reserved!

EDIT2: I just swapped the ram cards, nothing happened. I had a suspicion that it was that, but I guess not.

Comment: It's a BIOS issue. Many older BIOS have a 4GB cap on memory, from which video memory is deducted. To dig deeper, we need to know the make and model of the PC. Could be HP EliteBook 8770w or 8570w, 6470b, 6570b, 8470w, 8470p, 8570p, or the Pavilion dv7-2250em .

Comment: Ya sure? Windows still says 12gb available, take a look at the edit I made just now.

Comment: Then go ahead and unreserve it. Have a nice day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [12GB of RAM only 8GB is usable on Windows 7 64-bit](https://superuser.com/questions/456389/12gb-of-ram-only-8gb-is-usable-on-windows-7-64-bit)

Comment: “Is this just a bug with Windows 10 Update 1909?” - What you describe absolutely is not a bug in Windows 10.  People have asked about the behavior you describe for years, it’s absolutely due to the configuration of your firmware, and is absolutely not a bug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my usable RAM only half of my Installed RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/1514018/why-is-my-usable-ram-only-half-of-my-installed-ram)

Comment: I found a solution that might work. I looked at a website that had multiple different solutions to this problem, one being that I should reseat the ram in different spots. I didn't believe them, so I skipped that. But I realized that might work after all, as one stick is being used for regular computing, while the other is reserved for hardware. I won't try that now, but I will later today.

Comment: Just to make sure: Your system/cpu is x64 but is your Windows version also a 64bit version? For a 32bit Windows version the 4GB cap would make sense..

Comment: Yea, I'm pretty sure it is 64 bit.

Comment: Hello there! I have a new computer now so it is no longer much of an issue. I will be not be deleting this question, but I will be ignoring any replies.

Answer (score 2):

According to the
HP Pavilion dv6 Entertainment PC Maintenance and Service Guide,
these are the possible memory configurations for the HP Pavilion DV6-1355dx:

[image]

The maximum is then 8 GB (2 x 4 GB), so the additional 8 GB RAM that you
bought cannot work for you. I suggest returning it to the shop.

I think that the most you can add is one RAM stick of 4 GB, as you already
have one installed. It is best if the one you buy is of the exact same
model as the one that came with the computer.
This is to ensure that dual-channeling will work to improve performance.

Otherwise, as fitting RAM to motherboard is quite complicated,
it is safer to use a scanner such available from
[Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/)
that will detect your existing computer hardware and suggest a memory
upgrade.

---

(old answer)

One possibility is that for some reason the 8.5 GB that are hardware reserved
are actually allocated to the integrated display adapter.
Being integrated, this adapter has no Video RAM (VRAM) of its own and uses
part of your RAM.

To view the amount of video RAM in Windows 10:

- Run *Settings > System > Display*
- Click *Advanced display settings*
- Select the monitor and click its link for *Display adapter properties*
- The video RAM is listed in the *Adapter* tab next to "Dedicated Video Memory:".

If the amount of VRAM is excessive, this can be changed in the BIOS and may be called
something close to "Graphics Settings", "Video Settings", or "VGA Share Memory Size".

If you find nothing, check the Windows registry for the key
*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\GMM*. If the key exists and has an item
named `DedicatedSegmentSize` which contains the reserved amount in megabytes.
Its supposed maximal value is 512, which equals only 512 MB, but check it anyway.

If you still have found nothing, then the RAM you bought probably does not fit
the motherboard (a mistake that is easy to do).

Comment: Firstly, probably should have mentioned that my Internal Graphics is AMD Radeon. Secondly, I didn't find anything in settings. Thirdly, the options in my BIOS are very sparse, having only diagnostic options, time options, and a few others, but none mentioning anything having to do with Video or Graphics settings. Kinda stupid that they didn't have any more options other than that.

Comment: You should also add your computer or motherboard models and the RAM that you added.

Comment: I'll try and hunt down the motherboard type. So far though, the HP listing for specifications for this specific laptop (a 1355dx) did not mention the motherboard, so I may have to look it up, or ask a friend of mine who was very helpful in fixing it once by replacing the motherboard. He probably knows in that case what model it is.

Comment: If this is the HP Pavilion DV6-1355dx, then this is enough. What is the RAM?

Comment: Note that according to the manual, the max possible is 8 GB (2 x 4 GB). How have you reached 12 GB?

Comment: Well, sorry to admit, all its doing is reserving 2 3rds of the total ram, not like not allowing me to use it. Thing is, all of the online tutorials I've found haven't worked for me or I am not willing to try it because it is likely not the problem.

Comment: What happens in such cases depends on the motherboard. It may detect the memory, or the BIOS does, but it may be unable to use it.

Comment: I mean like windows is keeping me from using it.

Comment: It's not Windows, it's the motherboard.

Comment: I do know though, that some of the old 4gb stick that i was using was also reserved.