# Windows 10 reserving 4GB of RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory

i recently got a computer (second hand) which runs with no issues. 
[Specs, as shown in Settings. NOTE: There is also a 4GB GTX 1050TI installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCDZI.png)

However, only 3.95GB of the 8GB is marked as usable, with the other 4.1GB marked as "Hardware Reserved." I tried running Windows Memory Diagnostic, which came back clean. I looked at "msconfig > boot > Advanced" which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l7rf.png).

As far as i'm aware, my BIOS doesn't seem to have any memory-related settings in it.

Any help is appreciated, and don't hesitate to ask for any more information.

Comment: Check that memory sticks are secure and well fitted. Remove them and refit them if necessary.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like one of your 4GB RAM sticks is loose, or dual-channel is unsupported, or disabled, on your motherboard. If you have more than two RAM slots, try to place your sticks differently, for example by leaving an empty slot between them, and alternate (slot 1 and 3, slot 2 and 4, slot 1 and 4) until it's fully recognized and usable. Booting in Safe Mode can also help, sometimes. Also take a look at DanO's 1st answer here (https://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7), there's good insight in there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is all my extra RAM marked as "hardware reserved" in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7)

Comment: @Mokubai I've double checked both sticks, and they seem secure

Comment: @Didier I tried switching them over, but it refused to post. I only have the two slots, too. I checked CPU-Z, and it said it is single channel. However, the BIOS said (when I forgot to plug in my keyboard :/ ) it is dual channel. I'm still struggling to figure this out, especially when the bios says it is functioning. At this point, I'm considering a windows reinstall

Comment: You can reinstall Windows if you think it'll help, but there seems to be a problem with either one of your RAM sticks, or one of your RAM slots in the motherboard. If you switch them, your PC doesn't POST at all? Not even once after several attempts? Have you tried to boot in Safe Mode? It sure looks like a hardware issue to me, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Didier nope! The light comes on, it makes sounds, but that's it. Neither screen displays anything. However, putting the ram in their original configuration fixed it

Comment: Fixed it, as in "all 8GB are accounted for and usable"?

Comment: @Didier ah. Sorry, I forgot to post the final solution. It turns out that one of the sticks are dead, but still registering on the computer. The solution seems to be new ram, which I've ordered from Amazon. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Oh, OK, no problem. You've identified the cause, you've found a solution, what more can we hope for?! Cheers mate!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my usable RAM only half of my Installed RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/1514018/why-is-my-usable-ram-only-half-of-my-installed-ram)

Comment: @JasonChesters-salt if a module was faulty and replacing it is a fix then you might want to post that as an answer. You should be able to self-accept after a day or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that one of the sticks are dead, but still registering on the computer. The solution seems to be new ram, which I've installed, and all 8 gigs are now recognised and functioning.